# percentage of sensitivity predicted by the model

Tags: pca, lda

In PCA/LDA, how to find the percentage of positive cases predicted by the model in a particular class?
For example,suppose, Load_digits data set has 10 classes. how to check the percentage of 5th class predicted by the model?

Answer (score 0):

```
we will use 3 common metrics to assess the quality of the model recall,precision,F1 score.
 
Precision: Percentage of correct positive predictions relative to total positive predictions.

ie., Precision=TP/(TP+FP) 


Recall: Percentage of correct positive predictions relative to total actual positives.

ie.,Recall= TP/(TP+TN) 


`print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))` to find the metrics for each class.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).